# Difference between "evolve into" and "devolve into"

Tags: meaning, comprehension

What is the difference between "evolve into" and "devolve into"?

Example:

- ***Evolve into savages.***
- ***Devolve into savages.***

Is that similar or not?

Comment: The terms are essentially opposite in meaning, but mean similar things in the context that you have provided. Evolve [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/evolve) means to develop gradually, generally with the implication of becoming better, while devolve [Lexico 2](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/devolve) means to degenerate, to become worse. So, if you're talking about someone turning from a civilised human being to an uncivilised human being, devolved would fit the context more accurately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Evolve" conveys the notion of progression, moving forward: "a process of continuous change from a lower, simpler, or worse to a higher, more complex, or better state". ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolution)).

"Devolve" conveys the notion of regression, going backwards or down: "a downward evolution to a lower state" ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devolve)).

Note that "evolve" can also mean simply "unfold" or "move in a certain direction" ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolution)). But in contrast with "devolve", it does not have the same connotation of a downward movement or deterioration.